# Angular - How to iterate through an object and render children if they are present

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a Dto which has a child Dto of the same class like so:

```js
export interface KeywordDto {
  children?: null | Array<KeywordDto>;
  id?: number;
  name?: null | string;
  parent?: KeywordDto;
}
```

And the nested limit in theory can be unlimited (it won't be), but the point is that we won't know how many times this will be nested. So I want to have a method that can take a `KeywordDto`, check for children then render that child and do the same for that Dto, and so on...

Here is my current attempt:

```
<mat-accordion multi>
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let keyword of keywords">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                {{ keyword.name }}
            </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <div [innerHTML]="renderKeywordChildren(keyword)"></div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

```js
renderKeywordChildren(keyword: KeywordDto) {
  if (keyword.children?.length! > 0) {
    return `<mat-accordion multi>
      <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="{{let keyword of keywords}}">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                {{ keyword.name }}
            </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          
        <div [innerHTML]="renderKeywordChildren(keyword)"></div>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>`;
  }

  return;
}
```

So the issue with this is that the returning string doesn't know about the Angular templating, it will just print out `{{ keyword.name }}`.

Comment: What are you not defining the <mat-** tags directly in the html files? It seems to be the correct approach with *ngFor.

Comment: Would say you should look *ngIf and ng-template instead of build the string template.

Comment: That is how Ive just figured it out, will include the code in the answer shortly, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question!

Your expected result will be nesting of the same template based on `children`.

Besides using `<ng-template>` with `*ngIf` will be simpler, the critical point is how to pass the value into the nested template and how the nested template uses the received value as variable.

```
<ng-container
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="keywordTemp"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ keywords: keywords }"
>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #keywordTemp let-keywords="keywords">
  <mat-accordion multi>
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let keyword of keywords">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
          {{ keyword.name }}
        </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>

      <ng-container
        *ngIf="(keyword.children?.length ?? 0) > 0"
        [ngTemplateOutlet]="keywordTemp"
        [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ keywords: keyword.children }"
      >
      </ng-container>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
</ng-template>
```

*Note: You may compare the previous version with the current version which improves in reducing code duplication.*

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5hrtxv?file=src/app/app.component.html)